# Magento Cron Job Fatal Error

Tags: magento, centos, cron

I am using CentOs server for my Magento website. Somehow my magento cron jobs were not running, so I have checked using " crontab -l " command to verify whether there is any cron configure or not, but I found nothing, then I have configured crontab using "crontab -e" command and enter the magento cron.php path in crontab.

**

```
Error message
E_ERROR: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 32 bytes)
Stack trace
…ement::fetchAll called at /var/www/vhosts/syspro/lib/Zend/Db/Statement/
Pdo.php (290)
…do::fetchAll called at /var/www/vhosts/syspro/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/
Abstract.php (735)
…/www/vhosts/syspro/app/code/core/Mage/Eav/Model/Entity/Collection/
Abstract.php (1111)
…vhosts/syspro/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Resource/Product/
Collection.php (480)
…/www/vhosts/syspro/app/code/core/Mage/Eav/Model/Entity/Collection/
Abstract.php (874)
…Abstract::load called at /var/www/vhosts/syspro/lib/Varien/Data/
Collection.php (741)
…vhosts/syspro/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Resource/Product/
Collection.php (1493)
…hosts/syspro/app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Resource/Quote/Item/
Collection.php (182)
…hosts/syspro/app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Resource/Quote/Item/
Collection.php (139)
…:_afterLoad called at /var/www/vhosts/syspro/lib/Varien/Data/Collection/
Db.php (587)
…ction_Db::load called at /var/www/vhosts/syspro/lib/Varien/Data/
Collection.php (741)
…ator called at /var/www/vhosts/syspro/app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/
Quote.php (774)
…ar/www/vhosts/syspro/app/code/community/Ebizmarts/AbandonedCart/Model/
Cron.php (273)
…ar/www/vhosts/syspro/app/code/community/Ebizmarts/AbandonedCart/Model/
Cron.php (154)
…ar/www/vhosts/syspro/app/code/community/Ebizmarts/AbandonedCart/Model/
Cron.php (95)
…ar/www/vhosts/syspro/app/code/community/Ebizmarts/AbandonedCart/Model/
Cron.php (36)
in Ebizmarts_AbandonedCart_Model_Cron::abandoned called at ? (?)
…ay called at /var/www/vhosts/syspro/app/code/core/Mage/Cron/Model/
Observer.php (325)
…ob called at /var/www/vhosts/syspro/app/code/core/Mage/Cron/Model/
Observer.php (72)
…ispatch called at /var/www/vhosts/syspro/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/
App.php (1338)
…rMethod called at /var/www/vhosts/syspro/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/
App.php (1317)
…ge_Core_Model_App::dispatchEvent called at /var/www/vhosts/syspro/app/
Mage.php (448)
in Mage::dispatchEvent called at /var/www/vhosts/magento/cron.php (77)
```

**

Don't know what happen, I am not very friendly with CentOs.

Please help me to solve this issue.

Comment: Increase the memory_limit in php.ini file or in .htaccess add this line `php_value memory_limit 512M` or in root index.php add `ini_set('memory_limit', '512M'); `

Answer (score 0):

You have your php.ini memory_limit set to 134M. Magento likes at least 256 minimum, and at least 512 if possible. In your php.ini file, find the memory_limit = line and change it. If you're on a shared hosting provider, you may have to contact them to increase it for you.

Comment: And if you are having a memory error when running scripts, you need to check your distribution's location of its master `php.ini` files as it probably has separate configurations for Apache DSO, command line and php-fpm instances of the PHP interpreter. Command Line is not affected by `memory_limit` settings in `.htaccess`

Comment: Thank you! I have updated the memory limit in php.ini and it seems to be fixed the issue.